# Linux kernel transparent huge pages (thp) active on EC2 instances?

Tags: linux, memory-management, amazon-ec2

I run Java on EC2 instances with large memory requirements. (running on AMI version 2013.09)

I want to use the -XX:+UseLargePages in my JVM launch options.

When I do cat /proc/vmstat | grep thp
I see :
thp_fault_alloc 0
thp_fault_fallback 0
thp_collapse_alloc 0
thp_collapse_alloc_failed 0
thp_split 0

additionnally, when I do sudo cat /proc/vmstat | grep huge
I see :
nr_anon_transparent_hugepages 0

does it mean that Transparent Huge Pages are already active on my instance ?

Anything else I should configure on my instance (kernel, security group, security limits, etc.) ?

Currently, when I do "java -XX:+UseLargePages -version" to test the option, my ssh session will hang as the java command never returns.

regards

didier

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem, and in looking for the causes, I came across an article (link below) which states: "EC2 instances essentially come in two flavours of virtualization: paravirtualization (PVM) and hardware virtualization (HVM). The vast majority of EC2 AMIs use PVM, but for a variety of reasons, only EC2 instances using HVM can allocate hugepages."

A table is provided containing EC2 instance types that may support hugepages in your case.  I haven't tried it myself, but I hope this helps.

["Linux hugepages for Oracle on Amazon EC2: Possible, but not convenient, easy or fully supported"](http://www.pythian.com/blog/linux-hugepages-for-oracle-on-amazon-ec2-possible-but-not-convenient-easy-or-fully-supported/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20PythianGroupBlog%20%28Pythian%20Group%20Blog%29)

Comment: Link is not available :-(